# Приветствую, мне не понятно как соединить декомпозированную логику проекта на react

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Для начала есть множество api запросов, у всех у них один корневой сервер пример:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/articles')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result,
                    })
                }
```

И я понимаю, что бегать по разным документам и менять url в продакшне это долго, есть ли способ написать один url, и импортировать его во все api запросы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть npm пакет [**dotenv**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) и он включен в `react-scripts` начиная с версии `0.9.0`

[**Документация**](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

1. Добавьте `.env` файл в корень проекта
2. Имя глобальных переменных должна начинаться с `REACT_APP_`

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

**App.js**

```
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/articles`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result,
                    })
                }
```